# Overcoming 1mb file restriction in GAE Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

As if for now, we are using datastore blob to store profile images of our site. And there is restriction in Datastore for storing more than 1mb file as a blob in datastore. Is there any work around for this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html).

> Google App Engine includes the Blobstore service, which allows apps to serve data objects that can be up to 2 gigabytes in size. These objects are called Blobstore values, or blobs. Blobstore values are served as responses from request handlers and are created as uploads via web forms. Apps do not create blob data directly; instead, blobs are created indirectly, by a submitted web form or other HTTP POST request. Blobstore values can be served to the user, or accessed by the app in a file-like stream, using the Blobstore API.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* work around this by splitting the blob into multiple pieces and storing them in separate entities. What you should do, though, is use the Blobstore as @Thilo suggests.

Comment: What would be nice is to be able to upload an image that is larger than 1Mb, then resize it to smaller than 1Mb (so that you can save it to the datastore) without having to use the blobstore.  At the moment the image library does not allow this, which is a shame.

Comment: @jonmiddleton Why are you trying to avoid using the blobstore, though?

Comment: Do not get me wrong, I really like the blobstore and used it to store large files, but for profile images for example that do not have to be very large they could easily be saved as a standard blob.  The blob store has a few additional overheads, uploading using ajax is more tricky and having to do a custom bulkloader also adds overhead.  Using a standard blob also enables you to run the save in a transaction if you want.  I may well have some of these assumptions wrong so would love to be corrected :)